# How to test react component with setState in react testing library with Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-testing-library

I have two components in typesciprt. The parent component creates the state and passs the state and setState to the child component and the child component receives this setState.

parent.tsx

```
function TestParent():JSX.Element {
  const [testResult, setResult] = useState<IResult | null>(null)
  return (
    <TestChild setResult={setResult}/>
  )
}
```

child.tsx

```
interface IProps {
  setResult: Dispatch<SetStateAction<IResult | null>>
}

function TestChild(props: IProps): JSX.Element {
  ...
}
```

When I test child.tsx on child.test.tsx, it says `setResult is missing`:

```
test('render component correctly', () => {
  render(<TestChild/>
  ...
}
```

How should I pass the missing `setResult` attribute to pass the typescript check?

Comment: You have to pass the `setResult` prop in your `TestChild` test, e.g. `render(<TestChild setResult={jest.fn()} />`.